# Hangman Console Application

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I am currently working on a small project where I am creating a hangman game as a console application. Currently, I am having problems because I want to create an array for the word that is to be guessed. This word is not random and will always be the same. In this case, it is "miller". I want to create an array for "miller" and have a loop to display each letter in the word character array. When the letter is guessed correctly, I want to display the correct letter and if not display the special character "*" in its stead. So, for instance, the word is "miller" and would be first displayed as "******". When the user guessed a letter correctly, one special character would become the correctly guessed letter. So, say the user guesses "i"...the displayed word would then be "*i****". Say he guesses "l" next...the displayed word would then be "*ill**". How would I go about doing this? This is my code so far... I've created already attempted to create an array for this. Sorry if this seems trivial, but I am new to programming and just need some guidance and help.

TLDR;
I need help with this code. I am trying to make an array containing 'miller' and I want to be able to call on that array when the user guesses a letter correct changing the display of a special character "*" to whatever the letter he guesses correctly is. I am told going about a for loop is the best route for this, but I'm kind of lost. Help?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        char[] guessed = new char[26];

        char[] word = "miller".ToCharArray();

        char guess;

        int score = 0, index = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("******");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            Console.Write("Please enter a letter to guess: ");

            guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (guess == l1 || guess == l2 || guess == l3 || guess == l4 || guess == l5 || guess == l6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is correct.");
                guessed[index] = guess;
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is incorrect.");
                score++;
            }



        }

        Console.WriteLine("Your score is " + score);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: As a side note, I forgot to say that I had originally had each letter defined as a variable. So, the variable "l1" would contain 'm', "l2" would contain 'i', and so forth. They were made to be char variables as well. I forgot to mention that and change that before posting. Thanks!

Comment: Start by breaking the problem down into smaller pieces. This question is too large to get useful help with without someone just doing it for you

Comment: I don't think so. My only need is for help to formulate the array and how to create the for loop to change the special characters. I don't need someone to write the code for me. A simple pseudocode can help.

Comment: Then please slim down your question to focus on only the particular piece you need help with. Right now it reads like an entire homework problem

Comment: The post at hand only asks help for those two things. I am giving examples for most of the post so as to elaborate instead of being unclear as to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding your question because it is very verbose and unclear at the moment. Slimming it down would help with that

Comment: @user5927290 in that case, please rewrite your question and include *juts the code* for the loop to change special characters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you were looking for, maybe you should be more specific next time... but I tried to create a solution for your problem.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] guessed = new char[26];
        char[] testword = "******".ToCharArray();
        char[] word = "miller".ToCharArray();
        char[] copy = word;

        char guess;

        int score = 0, index = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(testword);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            Console.Write("Please enter a letter to guess: ");

            guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bool right = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < copy.Length; j++)
            {
                if (copy[j] == guess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your guess is correct.");
                    testword[j] = guess;
                    guessed[index] = guess;
                    index++;
                    right = true;
                }
            }

            if (right != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is incorrect.");
                score++;
            }
            else
            {
                right = false;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(testword);


        }

        Console.WriteLine("Your score is " + score);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `using System.Linq;` in your file and here is your for loop.

```
for (int 1 = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter a letter to guess: ");
    char guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if(word.Contains(guess))//checks if the word is is the array word
    {
        //the guess was correct.
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is correct.");
        guessed[index] = guess;
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        //the guess was wrong.
        console.WriteLine("Your guess is incorrect.");
        ....
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're fairly close to there.  The two things I'm uncertain about is the if statement "guess == l1 || guess == l2" etc etc...This can be handled with:

```
if(word.Contains(guess))
```

Second, you will need another for loop to go through the correctly guessed letters and place them.

for loop to fill in letters instead of asterisks:
put it at the beginning of for (int i = 10...)

```
for (int j = 0; j < word.Length; j++)
{
   if (guessed.Contains(word[j]))
   {
      Console.Write(word[j]);
   }
   else
   {
      Console.Write("*");
   }
}
```